# JPQL query returns NullPointerException even though the query works in console

Tags: java, jpa, combobox, javafx-8, eclipselink

I'm trying to populate a comboBox with names from a table/entity.

I am able to insert data and I can see the data in the table just fine.

The problem is when I build a query or typed query using an object off of the same class I used to insert (an EntityManager) it returns an NullPointerException.

I tried changing the type of data the ComboBox receives, type of List the .getResultList() method returns. Tried changing the query to a NamedQuery.

The query should return a list of names.

NamedQuery:

```
@NamedQuery(name="Equipe.getNomes", query="SELECT e.nome FROM TbEquipesEntity AS e")
```

Method to get data and populate combobox:

```
@FXML
    public void popula_box_edicao_camp(){

        try{
            TypedQuery<TbEquipesEntity> query =
 DaoConecta.em.createNamedQuery("Equipe.getNomes",TbEquipesEntity.class);

            List<TbEquipesEntity> list_equipes = query.getResultList(); 

            for(TbEquipesEntity t : list_equipes){      comboBox_equipes.getItems().addAll(t.getNome());
            }
        } catch(NullPointerException err){
            System.out.println("ComboBox Camp: Nenhuma equipe na lista");
        }


    }
```

Ultimately, what I need is the names to be inserted into the ComboBox but for now I can't even get the query to return the data.

This is a school project so I completely new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong.

I wasn't  connecting to the Database.